# Define a Swift typealias for any object that implements multiple protocols

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

I'm trying to define a `typealias` for a UITableViewCell's delegate property that conforms to multiple protocols. This is what I'm trying to do and Swift complains that my syntax is wrong:

```
// The typealias definition
typealias CellDelegate = AnyObject<UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

// In my UITableViewCell subclass:
weak var delegate: CellDelegate?
```

"Cannot specialize the non-generic type AnyObject" is the error I'm getting. How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The code that you posted has a different meaning from what you'd expect. You're treating `AnyObject` like a generic type, with `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate` as type arguments. It's the same thing as creating a `Dictionary` with `Int` keys and `String` values, for example:

```
var someDictionary: Dictionary<Int, String>
```

What you're trying to accomplish needs a different construct, called *protocol composition*. Swift provides it specifically to express types that conforms to multiple protocols. Its syntax is the following, you can use it anywhere you can use regular types:

```
FirstProtocol & SecondProtocol
```

Using this feature, your code would become:

```
// The typealias definition
typealias CellDelegate = UIPickerViewDataSource & UIPickerViewDelegate

// In my UITableViewCell subclass:
weak var delegate: CellDelegate?
```

Protocol composition is explained in Apple's guide to the Swift language, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID282).

**EDIT:** Updated to Swift 3 syntax, thanks @raginmari

Comment: In Swift 3 the syntax has changed to `typealias CellDelegate = UIPickerViewDataSource & UIPickerViewDelegate`.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to declare multiprotocol:

```
protocol<A, B>
```

Answer (score 2):

With Swift 3, the syntax changed.

Until Swift 2.3:

`typealias CellDelegate = protocol<UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>`

Since Swift 3:

`typealias CellDelegate = UIPickerViewDataSource & UIPickerViewDelegate`

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you type like this`weak var delegate: <CellDelegate>?`and why you don't type`weak var delegate: CellDelegate?`

The problem is that AnyObject is generic. With the first line you try to make AnyObject non-generic,and it isn't.

You better make a class that implement those (the datasource and the delegate).

Comment: Ah, the angle brackets--I just forgot to remove them from what exactly my intended  `typealias` is.

Comment: `AnyObject` is not a generic type, it actually is a protocol to which all classes conform, which is what the compiler error says: "Cannot specialize the **non-generic type** AnyObject"

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a known object,AnyObejct is too generic,and thats why you can't do it